# Accessibility: Related Content - Two fingers flick

Tags: accessibility, uiaccessibility, tvos11

[image: TV OS Accessibility]

I have been trying to understand the intent and potential use case to use "Two finger flick right" as explained under Voice over help section on Apple TV. So far my understanding is

- Two finger flick right allows voice over to focus on something that is otherwise non-focusable, without moving system focus.
- In case of attached screen shot, a user is able to get hint for focus menu option and know more about the option (in this case it will be "Two finger flick right" under the Apple TV logo.

I have been trying to find a good use case where someone may have used it or is aware of any documentation around it's implementation.

[image]

This is what my code looks like so far in terms of accessibility attributes

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? AccessibilityTableViewCell else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

    cell.titleLabel.text = "Main title for row \(indexPath.row)"
    cell.titleLabel.textColor = .black

    cell.isAccessibilityElement = true
    cell.accessibilityLabel = "Main title for row \(indexPath.row)"
    cell.accessibilityHint = "Hint for Main title at row for index \(indexPath.row)"
    cell.accessibilityTraits |= UIAccessibilityTraitStaticText

    return cell
}
```

What additional needs to be set to make the hint label as related content to row 2?